# how to retrieve data from microsoft sql server and show it in android app

Tags: android, mysql, server

how to retrieve data from microsoft sql server and show it in android app.
Database value already present in DB(connection with jdbc:jtds:sqlserevr)

Comment: Write a Web service that communicates with the database. Have your app work with the Web service.

Comment: actually, i am not using any web service.

Comment: That's why he suggested you create one.  Also look for answers to your questions before asking.  You're far from the first person to ask this.